# Oracle - Error "missing left parenthesis" when CREATE TABLE

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, create-table

I'm using Oracle SQL Developer for learning and implementing SQL Queries. But every time I try to Create Table, it gives an error and I'm not sure what's exactly I'm missing. See the image to see the error:

[image]

**EDIT:**

[image]

Comment: Table without any column? Maybe you should search for better tutorial. `CREATE TABLE table2(col_name NUMBER);`

Comment: @lad2025 see the problem. It is not I dunno about adding columns in a table. I don't know why it is showing me "missing left parenthesis in line 1"? See this image even with column as you said http://prntscr.com/glscvn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the comma sign after the column definition. You can use them if there are multiple columns, but not when only one column. Look the following example -

```
Create Table A (
i int,
j int
);
```

and for one column -

```
Create Table A (
i int
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to define columns:

```
CREATE TABLE table2(col_name NUMBER);
```

> It is not I dunno about adding columns in a table. **I don't know why it is showing me "missing left parenthesis in line 1"**?

So let's check official documentation of [CREATE TABLE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7002.htm):

[image]

> **Each of the clauses following the table name is optional for any given relational table. However, for every table you must at least specify either column names and datatypes using the relational_properties clause or an AS subquery clause using the table_properties clause.**

As you see you have to use `(` and `)` for relational properties.

**EDIT:**

> See this image even with column as you said

And now you have different error: `invalid identifier`. You have to remove `,`:

```
CREATE TABLE table(
  ID NUMBER(2) --, causes error
);
```

From doc:

[image]

As you see you cannot have `,` without other column definition.

Maybe you saw this pattern in different RDBMS like `SQL Server`:

```
CREATE TABLE tab
(
    a INT,   -- yes it works and could be very handy when editing 
);
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/NAWX62111)**

Answer (score 0):

Table should have atlease a column.

create table table_name (column_name datatype);

Comment: I have added the column still the same kind of error is coming.

Comment: Boss, have you replaces the data type with actual data type?           CREATE TABLE customers
( customer_id number(10) 
);